# Can only change "stop-color" once with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg, colors

my function is as easy as this:

```
function changeColor(color, opacity, obj) {
    var colors = obj.getElementsByClassName("color_elem");

    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        mainInterface.makeToast("Color " + i + ": " + color);
        colors[i].style.stopColor = color;
        colors[i].style.stopOpacity = opacity;
        //colors[i].setAttribute("stop-color", color);
        //colors[i].setAttribute("stop-opacity", opacity);
    }
}
```

This function can be called multiple times. It's triggered either from an button click event, or through an interface. As parameters it gets a color like`#FFFFFF`, an opacity ranging from 0 to 1 and an obj which in any case is an svg element.

When calling the function first, it changes the color like I would expect it. Calling it the second time, it won't. It will keep the color it was assigned by the first function call.

With `mainInterface.makeToast("Color " + i + ": " + color);` I ensured that I actually have the correct color, which i have.

I tried using css properties, aswell as attributes. (See comment)

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Can you put up all the relevant code (including the HTML) here or on jsbin.com / jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: can we have some more codes please !

Comment: If I understand you function clearly enough, `.color_elem` are `<stop>` elements inside a gradient. Your function applies on all of them the same color. Then why use a gradient and not simply change their `fill` property ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a **bug** in some browsers, I had the same problem in Chrome (62.0.3202.94) and Opera (49.0.2725.39) but worked perfectly in Firefox Dev (58.0b5) and Edge (38.14393.0.0).

In the browsers that didn't work SVG turned to correct color when window was resized; so my hack is to "modify" (and I say "modify" because you can keep the original value and also works) SVG height in JS code.

So if your SVG element is 100px height you can do this after you've changed stop-color:

```
$('#svg').attr("height","100px");
```

*(I used JQuery in the example because I couldn't make this hack work with pure JS, don't know why sorry)*